# Spring boot Test tries to connect to Database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockmvc

I'm trying to run test cases for a project and encountered the following issue: When running test class it tries to connect to the database and fails giving the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at 
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cache': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'migrationPatternService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'migrationPatternService' defined in file [C:\Projects\cloud_genie\cloud-genie-microservice\target\classes\com\virtusa\gto\cloudgenie\service\MigrationPatternService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'commonDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jdbcTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=23.236.55.227)(port=3306)(type=master) : Socket fail to connect to host:23.236.55.227, port:3306. Connection timed out: connect
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely because you provided your Spring boot application.properties / -.yml file with liquibase or datasource properties.

You should override these properties in your test class.
By example for using a in memory database like H2.